# Is there a model of reconciliation in the Tanach?

Tags: history, tanach, mitzvah, derech-eretz-manners, rebuke-tochacha

Monica asked an [excellent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13819/971) about how to correct someone who posts something objectionable on a public forum.  I was struck by the suggestion that the usual course of action was "to take the person aside for a private conversation".  That's sensible advice and  (once you hear it) maybe a bit obvious.  But it's also what we [Christians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6115/914) are commanded to do.

So I got to wondering: Is this a case of convergent evolution (so to speak) or is this model of reconciliation found in the Tanach?  Or would the early Christians have heard it from their rabbis?

Comment: Note that Jacob seems to have rebuked Reuben, Simeon, and Levi in public (in the presence of the rest of his sons) in Genesis Chapter 49.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very conveniently, the answer lies plainly in one verse. [VaYikra (Leviticus) 19:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm) states, "Do not hate your brother in your heart; you surely must rebuke your neighbor, but you must not bear sin because of him." (My own translation)

[Rashi](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) there states: "but You shall not bear a sin on his account: I.e., [in the course of your rebuking your fellow,] do not embarrass him in public. — [Torath Kohanim 19:43; Arachin 16b]" ([translation from here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920/showrashi/true))

Answer (score 5):

Torah says:

> You shall surely admonish your fellow, but don't bear a sin because of him.

Which is interpreted as:

> Even when it's necessary to admonish someone, do so in such a way that you won't bear the sin of embarrassing him publicly.

Comment: Is the first quote [Leviticus 19:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm)?  Leviticus 19:18 works too, if you think through how you would prefer to be rebuked or admonished.

Comment: Yes, it's Lev. 19:17.