# Pointing out someone's deceitful actions or ways

Tags: sheker-false, rebuke-tochacha

Is there any problem with putting someone in their place? Let's say there is a person who is not truthful in their day to day activity, is a hypocrite, does things to fool people in order to get financial gain. And many people are really indeed fooled by such a person. Is there anything wrong with calling this person out and saying that perhaps what they're doing is wrong? Especially if their actions are sometimes against the Torah or what Chazal said, for example, if they ask for tzedeka although they are really not worthy.

I would say to tell other people would be lashon hara or perhaps motzei shem rah. However what about to address the person himself?

(Any sources one way or another would be helpful.)

Comment: Why would it be lashon hara to prevent people from being stolen from?

Comment: @DoubleAA Let's say it's a issue of people thinking he is a "Talmud Chacham" that learns the whole day (for this reason people give him money) when really just learns a few hours and wastes his time on other things...Perhaps this would be lashon hara?

Comment: Speech that would otherwise be lashon hara or motzei shem rah has some pretty strict requirements to avoid that status -- it has to be truthful (not just a rumor), it has to be necessary to prevent a harm, it has to be no more public than necessary, etc.  See Chofetz Chayim for a start.  So I would tread really carefully here.

Comment: This reads like you're putting a very thin veneer of hypotheticalness on a particular case (e.g. "Especially ..." and "ask for tzedaka"). (Not saying that it is, just that it unfortunately looks that way.) The way it's written, with layers of specificity, it's not clear how general it's supposed to be. I recommend [edit]ing the question either to be more genuinely general or to be clearly about a well-specified (though still hypothetical) case.

Comment: Who is not worthy of tzedakah?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a model of reconciliation in the Tanach?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14358/is-there-a-model-of-reconciliation-in-the-tanach)

Answer (score 3):

You ask if there's a problem with telling someone he's sinning. No, it's one of the 613 *mitzvos*, based on [Lev. 19:17](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%96). But there are ways to do it and ways not to: see e.g. [*Rambam*, *Deos* 6:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=2&perek=6&halocha=7):

> … gently, with soft language. He should make sure the fellow knows that he's telling him this only for his own benefit, to bring him to life in the world to come.…

Comment: There is a piece of gamoro in shabboth I think in 148-150 somewhere there, which states if people are am ho'orasSim and are ignorant in their ways, and you know for sure that if a you tell the person that they are doing something forbidden and they will still do it, you shouldn't tell them. For it is better to do a Malacho in shabboth unknowingly that it is daoraitho than doing the Malacho is forbidden daoraitho and still do it on shabboth. However it Is not the same as mamonoth sins as in this case.