# How do you do teshuva for saying lashon hara about someone that already passed away?

Tags: halacha, repentance-teshuvah, speech-talking, lashon-hara-slander

If someone might have said lashon hara by mistake unintentionally and quickly said something good, and the subject passed away. How can one do teshuvah?

Comment: If you spoke the L"H after the person passed away, read up on the details here http://didc.blogspot.com/2007/02/mitzvah-to-speak-lashon-hara.html

Comment: Hello user12318 and welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: What does "I might have said lashon hara by mistake I quickly said something good." mean? I can't parse it.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45424/1857

Comment: Side note: at least according to one opinion in Erchin 16a, you can't do teshuvah for Lashon Hara even if the person is alive. Not sure which way we pasken - there is a dissenting opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Chofetz Chaim (laws of L.H. 4:12) makes an important distinction between L.H. that actually eventually causes damage to the person one spoke about, and L.H. that never leads to damage. In the latter case, one needn't ask forgiveness from the person he spoke about; it is only *bein adam lmakom*, and the teshuvah process is the same as for any other *bein adam lmakom*.

In the former case it is indeed also *bein adam lchaveiro*, so the *teshuva* process would be the same as for other *aveiros* of this type when the victim has died: one must visit the victim's grave etc. (for details, see Shulchan Aruch O.C. 606:2 with M.B.)